# How do I Load a Command on a Specific TTY at Boot?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, boot, tty

I am setting up a Dumb Terminal which will connect to my build for Aesthetics™. To use the Dumb Terminal, I will need to have a separate keyboard till I get my present keyboard working and setting up a KVM for it. I don't fancy setting up the keyboard each time I want to use the Terminal, and it's not like I am going to be using the Terminal a crazy amount. Basically want to run a command on the Terminal, whether it be a Terminal Based system monitor I can gaze at when I need to, or even ASCII art. I don't care what the command is, but I need to know how to run that Command on the Serial TTY at boot. I don't have the terminal just yet, this is more me preparing for the terminal and what I want to do with it.

[This will be a serial connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431945/connecting-modern-linux-distributions-to-physical-terminals) setup like that. So:

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@device.service
```

then:

```
systemctl start serial-getty@device.service
```

Then the TTY will be something like ttyS* (eg. ttyS0 or ttyS1.) Technically I don't have a Serial Port, and will need to use a Serial-to-USB, so this may even be ttyUSB* (eg. ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1)

So, TL;DR:

I need run a command on boot, with an output, that displays something to the terminal, just like entering a command via your terminal emulator normally. What is the command/setup I need to run a Command on a Separate TTY at boot?

Comment: every systemd service has a file so you can use one for your needs in its syntax there is a line `TTYPath=/dev/tty2` for example TTYreset etc ... and `After=getty@tty2.service` still using tty2 example   to run it asap after tty2 is available. See systemd services syntax to make your own.

Comment: So I'd basically do:

`[Unit]`
`After=getty@device.service`

`[Service]`
`ExecStart=/path/to/command command`

Sounds straightforward, but will this output to the TTY/Terminal?